# Usability and distracting and confusing design

Tags: website-design, typography

I have designed my theme here you can take a look :

http://photontechs.com/themes/VSResume/Designer/

Reviewer said "Nice idea, but usability for this conversion is pretty low. Theme is also very distracting and confusing too. "

What does this mean ?

Comment: For a CV theme, it's well done & 1-page are good for hits. I don't see any navigation & it could help to have one. The review is obscure itself, he's using words that don't fit together in the context; usability for this conversion. Conversion shouldn't be used unless it describes goals you want to reach or visitors coming to the website & how these visits convert into contacting you using the form or buying a product, for example. And for usability and distracting elements, I think it's wrong. The theme is pretty clear & straight forward. In other words, sounds like a review from a competitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [Mystery Meat Navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation) (MMN) anti-pattern. In MMN the information on what things do is not visible until you hover over them. This is bad, for several reasons. For example it stops users flow and in your case its not readily apparent that there is navigation in first place.

Please Note: You are going to get better answers on [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)